# Extract content from multiple txt files, then save files based on folder.filename

Tags: powershell

I need search then extract content from multiple txt files and then save each search result to separate txt files, e.g. `serverabc.systeminfo.txt`.

The below works however it returns all results to a single systeminfo.txt file that does not list what folder/file the results came from.

Ideally I need a single file output for each systeminfo extraction. In the extracted folder there are multiple folders i.e. abc123, def456 etc. Each file needs to search systeminfo file within for either "abc software" or "def software" then if found output that result to a single text file, i.e. `abc123.systeminfo` etc.

Once these files have been saved they will then be compared against a `master.txt` file for differences.

```
$path = "H:\Compare\Extracted"
$Text = "abc Software"
$Text2 = "def Software"
$Results = "H:\Compare\Results\$($file.name).txt"
$files = Get-ChildItem $path -recurse -Include *.txt

foreach ($file in $files) {
    Get-Content $file |
       Select-String -Pattern $Text, $Text2 |
       select line |
       Out-File $Results -Append
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `$file` isn't known outside (and particularly before) the `foreach` loop. Put the definition of `$Results` inside the loop and the code should work. Also, I think you should add `-Expand` to the `select` statement to expand the `Line` property.

```
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $Results = "H:\Compare\Results\$($file.Directory.Name + '.' + $file.Name).txt"
    Get-Content $file |
        Select-String -Pattern $Text, $Text2 |
        select -Expand Line |
        Out-File $Results -Append
}
```

Use `$file.BaseName` instead of `$file.Name` if you want the output file created without including the extension of the source file.

Comment: Hi, This still returns all results to a single file? I need to search all txt files in the H:\compare\extracted directory for the string of text and return the results to H:\compare\results\foldername.filename for each file found?

Comment: @dragonhsv I seriously doubt that you're getting all results in a single output file unless you have only one file showing matches, or you have multiple files with the same name. Please provide evidence. For including the folder name in the output filename see the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, sorry about the confusion, my mistake you are correct all file names are the same just different folders, i.e. severrname is "abc123" filenames are all "systeminfo.txt" Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the tip i have now added this to the script to rename all files and now it works.             <code> Get-ChildItem "H:\Compare\Extracted" -Filter *.txt -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Directory.Name+'_'+$_.Name} </code>                                                                                                                          Thank you once again for your help